# Serialization Breaks All Buttons

Tags: java, swing, serialization

While attempting to make my Java program save via serialization I encountered an issue: after loading, the buttons no longer function. From debugging I can tell that my load method is being called and de-serializing the data. Below is my Driver and FileIO classes, thanks in advance for any tips.

`

```
public class Driver {
static FileIO go;
static Display ack;
public static int result;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JOptionPane loader = new JOptionPane();
    result = loader.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to load a character?");
    if(result == 0){
        go = new FileIO(true);
        ack = go.load();
    }
    else if(result == 1){
        go = new FileIO(false);
        ack = new Display();
    }
    else{
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Bar bar = new Bar();
    ack.add(bar);
    ack.setVisible(true);

}
```

}`

```
public class FileIO {
private String output;
private File file;
File written;


public String getOutput() {
    return output;
}


public void setOutput(String output) {
    this.output += output;
}


public FileIO(boolean isLoading) {
    if(isLoading){
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20,30);
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if(status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            ta.setText("No File Chosen");
        }
        else{
            file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        }

    }
    else{
        try{
            File dir = new File("C:\\RPG Toolbar");
            dir.mkdir();
            file = new File("C:\\RPG Toolbar\\Hero.ser");

            if(file.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println("New Hero Made");
            }
            else{
                file = file.createTempFile("Hero", ".ser", dir);
                System.out.println("New Hero Made (with random num)");
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Send halp!");
        }
    }

}

public void save(){
    try{
        // Serialize data object to a file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(Driver.ack);
        out.close();

        // Serialize data object to a byte array
        /*ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos) ;
        out.writeObject(Driver.ack);
        out.close();*/
        System.out.println("Saved!");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Save failed!");
    }
}

public Display load(){
    Display x = null;

    try{
        FileInputStream door = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(door);
        x = (Display) reader.readObject();
        door.close();
        reader.close();
        System.out.println("Loaded!");
        }
    catch (Exception e){ 

        }

    return x;

}
```

}

Please be gentle, I'm new to Swing and new to serialization.

Comment: Never use empty catch blocks. Myself, I wouldn't serialize a GUI, but rather would serialize its non-GUI model that holds its state. I'd then build the GUI and apply its model, assuming that your program uses good MVC (model-view-control) separation. This is one important reason to use MVC and its siblings.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try separating out the visualization and the model then serializing the model.

Comment: You're probably having problems with the listeners not being serialized as they may be held in different classes.

Comment: *"Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of all JavaBeansTM has been added to the java.beans package. Please see XMLEncoder."* - From the JavaDocs for [`JComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html)

Comment: Just checked, it's serializing the listeners as well. The way I have it is the class that's being serialized has instances of all other classes, including the listeners.